# Is Web API 2 Controller thread safe? (datatables editor plugin)

Tags: c#, datatables

I am wondering if this code is thread safe,
This is taken from datatable editor c# API
https://editor.datatables.net/manual/net/webapi

```
public class StaffController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/staff")]
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Staff()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

        using (var db = new Database(settings.DbType, settings.DbConnection))
        {
            var response = new Editor(Db, "staff")
                .Model<StaffModel>()
                .Process(request)
                .Data();

            return Json(response);
        }
    }
}
```

What happen if few threads are entering `Staff()` method with an update? how it will affect the database?

**EDIT**
I am working with SQL database, the database should hold vital shared data and I am concern that it will break in the middle (like dead lock when 2 thread are updating the same data, is it even possible?)

Comment: It depends on the database. Normally if you are performing a *write* the table is locked by the sql server. If you're only doing reads, there's no point really in doing something "thread safe". What do you expect would happen with the database, and why? Have you investigated this before asking your question?

Comment: If you are worried about thread safety between multiple accesses, you could always use a transaction btw.

Comment: Each request will be handled by a separate controller instance so there won't be multiple threads entering the same Staff() method...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is thread safe, framework handles multiple concurrent requests by enqueuing them. For every request, a new instance of controller is created. By the way, you are only reading data, so no worries :)